# Querying phone records

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to use SQL to analyze this call data I have. The main question I want to answer is: If a caller dials a number and doesn't get a response the first time, does the value of `some_factor` (boolean column) impact the probability of the caller getting a response when redialing the same number later?

Here are the columns in this table:

```
| id | phone_number | callee_name | caller_id | call_duration | some_factor | created_at          |
|----|--------------|-------------|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------|
| 1  | 123-456-7890 | John Smith  | 42        |               | t           | 2022-03-07 09:40:40 |
```

Here was what I arrived at after some thinking, but I'm relatively inexperienced with SQL queries. If they worked, I could look at the ratio of the count from query 1 compared to the count from query 2, and then redo the queries where `some_factor` is false.

```sql
-- 1. successful retried calls: the callee picked up
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM phone_calls
WHERE phone_number IN (
    SELECT phone_number
    FROM phone_calls
    WHERE call_duration IS NULL
    AND some_factor
)
AND call_duration IS NOT NULL

-- 2. unsuccessful retried calls: the callee did not pick up
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM phone_calls
WHERE phone_number IN (
    SELECT phone_number
    FROM phone_calls
    WHERE call_duration IS NULL
    AND some_factor
)
AND call_duration IS NULL

-- then, do math with the results of these queries to get success rate when some_factor is true
-- then, redo but with AND NOT some_factor to get success rate when some_factor is false
```

But, I realized that 2 is counting entries from the subquery in the total count. I want the COUNT to not include the first time that someone called a number, if they did not pick up. Maybe if I can exclude entries with an `id` that corresponds to entries from the subquery, that will work. But I can't figure out how to do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you need the In clause. You can use some_factor outside the subquery and obtain the same result (and faster). Also the first query is confusing. call _duration IS NULL in the subquery and call_duration IS NOT NULL in outer query.

Comment: I want to find phone numbers for which the first time someone called them, they did not answer. If the callee picked up the very first time, I'm not interested in them for this analysis.

Comment: I don;t understand your queries - the first one presumably counts call that were successful but also had other calls not answered which is not what your comment describes, the second doesn't need any `in` criteria and surely is just a count where call_duration is null and some_factor is true?

Comment: so the second one returns the count larger by the number of phone numers in the subquery?

Comment: Sorry that this hasn't been as clear as I intended. I am using subqueries because I want to filter the table to only show phone numbers that someone unsuccessfully tried to call the very first time. Sometimes, people are successful the very first call, so I want to exclude those phone numbers from my query/analysis.

1. counts calls that were successful after the first, failed, attempt.
2. counts calls that were not successful after the first, failed, attempt.

I think 2. is including the first failed attempt in its sum

Comment: There is no correlation in your subqeries based on "first/second/before/after" - so what happens where you have the first call successful and a subsequent call unsuccessful?

Comment: That's part of the problem that I'm unsure how to solve with my query. For each phone number returned by the subquery, I want the entry it came from to have been the very first entry corresponding with that phone number. But I'm not sure how to write that out.

Comment: Maybe that would fit better in a different question though. The answer here answers the main question that I had written out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand in the second query you're not interested in the results returned by the subquery itself. So the count is as a result larger by the amount of distinct phone numbers returned by the subquery. You only need to subtract that number:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number)
FROM phone_calls
WHERE phone_number IN (
    SELECT phone_number
    FROM phone_calls
    WHERE call_duration IS NULL
    AND some_factor
)
AND call_duration IS NULL
```